# Read byte[] from server

Tags: java, datainputstream

I am trying to read `byte[]` that is being send from a client to a server.

This is my client code...

```
 din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA"); 
 // encrypt the aeskey using the public key 
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);

 byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(aesKey.getEncoded());
 dout.write(cipherText);
```

And this is my server code...

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());          
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

 String chiper = dis.readUTF();
 System.out.println(chiper);
```

However, the `dis.readUTF();` line fails with an exception...

```
java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at gameserver.ClientHandler.run(GameServer.java:65)
```

Could someone please help me understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean, "is not work?"  Does it fail to compile?  Fail at runtime with an exception?  What's the stack trace?

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at gameserver.ClientHandler.run(GameServer.java:65)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, if you write a sequence of (encrypted!) bytes at one end, and trying to read a UTF-formatted string at the other end...you're going to have a bad time.

I'd suggest that on the client side you should do something like

```
dout.writeInt(cipherText.length);
dout.write(cipherText);
```

and then on the server side you should do something like

```
int byteLength = dis.readInt(); // now I know how many bytes to read
byte[] theBytes = new byte[byteLength];
dis.readFully(theBytes);
```

Comment: +1 for 'bad time' reference... and being a good answer of course

Comment: is it possible to use objectoutstream to send the byte array?

Comment: THe first `write()` should be `writeInt()`.

Comment: @hkinterview: Possibly, but I don't think it will be as efficient.  It'll have some added overhead.

Answer (score 0):

`DataIputStream.readUTF()` is for data that you have written with DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`. You haven't written UTF so you can't read it.

This is binary data so you shouldn't be thinking about UTF or strings at all. Write the length of the array with `writeInt()`, then the array with `write()`. At the other end, read the length with `readInt()`, allocate a byte[] buffer that big and then read the ciphertext into it with `readFully()`.

Comment: i finally use objectOutputStream to send a string object to client.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to get the message with the read method and get the number of characters of the real messages and then convert this to a string

```
int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];

bytesRead = dis.read(messageByte);
String chiper = new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
System.out.println(chiper);
```

Answer (score -1):

on client side, you should convert the byte[] array to String and use 
`dout.writeUTF()` to send the converted String.

Comment: String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: @EJP I'm disagree with your words. String is not the preferred container for binary data but anyway, it can. Though it has beyond the scope of this question, sometimes String does be used as binary container in REST service.

Comment: It shouldn't be, unless the binary data is hex- or base64-encoded. The round trip isn't guaranteed to succeed unless you are really careful with your character sets.

Comment: I totally understand & agree your charset point. But the base64-encoded data does be a String, isn't it?